# Convert Callback to Clientside Callback

Tags: callback, plotly, plotly-dash, dashboard, plotly-python

I want to convert my dash app callbacks into client-side callbacks so that my app goes faster.

I have already read the [Dash Clientside callback documentation](https://dash.plotly.com/clientside-callbacks).

My problem is that I have huge callbacks and I don't have knowledge about `JavaScript`, so at the moment it's so difficult for me to apply the conversion.

I was wondering if someone could convert one of my app callbacks and then I will try to convert the rest taking that one as reference:

```
@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('figures_container', 'children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('version1_dropdown', 'value'),
     dash.dependencies.Input('version2_dropdown', 'value'),
     dash.dependencies.Input('lang_dropdown', 'value')])
     def version_figures(value1, value2, lang_value):
        if(lang_value is None or value1 is None or value2 is None):
            return dash.no_update
        else:
            versions_stats = R.versions_stats
            if lang_value == 'Spanish':
                if value1 == 'Oct 1st 2016':
                    entities_version1 = versions_stats[0]
                    df1 = R.instance_types_es_2016_10_01
                    
                if value1 == 'Oct 1st 2020':
                    entities_version1 = versions_stats[18]
                    df1 = R.instance_types_es_2020_10_01
                    
                if value1 == 'May 1st 2021':
                    entities_version1 = versions_stats[36]
                    df1 = R.instance_types_es_2021_05_01
                    
                if value1 == 'June 1st 2021':
                    entities_version1 = versions_stats[54]
                    df1 = R.instance_types_es_2021_06_01
                    
                if value2 == 'Oct 1st 2016':
                    entities_version2 = versions_stats[0]
                    df2 = R.instance_types_es_2016_10_01
                    
                if value2 == 'Oct 1st 2020':
                    entities_version2 = versions_stats[18]
                    df2 = R.instance_types_es_2020_10_01
                    
                if value2 == 'May 1st 2021':
                    entities_version2 = versions_stats[36]
                    df2 = R.instance_types_es_2021_05_01
                    
                if value2 == 'June 1st 2021':
                    entities_version2 = versions_stats[54]
                    df2 = R.instance_types_es_2021_06_01
            
            if lang_value == 'English':
                if value1 == 'Oct 1st 2016':
                    entities_version1 = versions_stats[72]
                    df1 = R.instance_types_en_2016_10_01
                if value1 == 'Oct 1st 2020':
                    entities_version1 = versions_stats[90]
                    df1 = R.instance_types_en_2020_10_01
                    
                if value1 == 'May 1st 2021':
                    entities_version1 = versions_stats[108]
                    df1 = R.instance_types_en_2021_05_01
                    
                if value1 == 'June 1st 2021':
                    entities_version1 = versions_stats[126]
                    df1 = R.instance_types_en_2021_06_01
                    
                if value2 == 'Oct 1st 2016':
                    entities_version2 = versions_stats[72]
                    df2 = R.instance_types_en_2016_10_01
                    
                if value2 == 'Oct 1st 2020':
                    entities_version2 = versions_stats[90]
                    df2 = R.instance_types_en_2020_10_01
                    
                if value2 == 'May 1st 2021':
                    entities_version2 = versions_stats[108]
                    df2 = R.instance_types_en_2021_05_01
                    
                if value2 == 'June 1st 2021':
                    entities_version2 = versions_stats[126]
                    df2 = R.instance_types_en_2021_06_01
            
            bar_figure = F.get_version_bar_figure([value1, value2], [entities_version1, entities_version2])
            pie_figure = F.get_version_pie_figure([value1, value2], [entities_version1, entities_version2])
            bar_graph = dcc.Graph(id='versions_bar', figure=bar_figure, style={'height':'26.041666666666668vw', 'width':'45.572916666666664vw', 'display': 'inline-block'})
            pie_graph = dcc.Graph(id='versions_pie', figure=pie_figure, style={'height':'19.53125vw', 'width':'45.572916666666664vw', 'display': 'inline-block'})
            title = html.H3(value1 + " VS " + value2)
            type_title = html.H3("DBpedia types comparison")
            types_container = html.Div([
                dcc.Graph(id='ontology_version', figure=F.ontology_figure, style={'height':'26.041666666666668vw', 'width':'39.0625vw', 'display': 'inline-block'}),
                dcc.Graph(id='instance_types_version', figure=F.get_versions_instance_types_figure([value1, value2], df1, df2), 
                                     style={'height':'26.041666666666668vw', 'width':'45.572916666666664vw', 'display': 'inline-block'})
                ]
                )
            return title, html.Br(), bar_graph, pie_graph, html.Hr(), type_title, types_container
```

As you can see, this callback takes items (`dataframes`, `lists`, `figures`...) from other local modules (`R`, `F`...). I don't know if it is possible to convert callbacks in this context.

Hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The main problem here is that when you make it a client side callback you can only have Javascript code inside and you can't refer to the Python modules inside the callback. So you would need to write Javascript code equivalent in function to what you use from your Python modules.

Comment: If you want more specific help with converting this you need to share a reproducible example. So that would be a callback that works when you run it as is.

Comment: Oh I understand now. So client side callbacks is not a solution for me. I will try with server side cache callbacks.